# Why the breakpoint set before run in GDB doesn't work?

Tags: linux, gdb, breakpoints

I typed these commands:

```
#gdb myprogram
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
```

But the program didn't stop at the entrance of the main function.

However, if I started the program first and then entered GDB and **attach**ed the process, I could set breakpoints which would work -- After I pressed **continue**, the program would stop at a breakpoint.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in a specific line.

Comment: If you type `start` instead of `run`, does it stop fairly soon after it starts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
(gdb) set backtrace past-main on
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40058a: file main.cpp, line 25.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/main
```

Comment: Thank you, Joster. But that didn't work for me either.